# Setting index.max_result_window IBM Watson Discovery Service

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I've researched Stack Overflow and found the method to increase this parameter if I have a `.yml` file for elastic search.  However, if I am running a python script accessing the Watson Discovery REST api, how do I do this?  I don't see the corresponding parameter in their on-line api reference.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?  The max result window in Discovery is 10,000, but we don't have same parameters as Elastic search. - (IBM Watson Employee)

Comment: Thank you.  I want to judge the sentiment of a particular topic, across all documents that are currently in the news feed.  For example, what is the sentiment over a particular date span for "ice cream" is positive or negative. (the number of pos, neg and neutral docs).   Thus, aggregate across every single document that has ice cream as keyword -- don't just look at the first ten thousand found within my date span.  I want the aggregation docSentiment.type counts returned ... BTW, I have no interest in seeing any of the  underlying XXX,0000 docs Watson found with "ice cream"